# How to add "(...)" underneath the last displayed line in case of y-overflow?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm having some text in an inline-block div with a fixed height and width: http://jsfiddle.net/Jeroen94/LUJ8S/1/. I've hidden the `y-overflow` with `overflow-y: hidden`, but that kind of cuts my words horizontally sometimes. Therefore, I'd like to add something like "(...)" underneath the last fully shown sentence with . The end result should look like:

> This is some text.
>
> This is some text.
>
> This is some text.
>
> (...)

Is it possible to do this with CSS?

Comment: There is a way to get this behavior with css. The property is called `text-overflow: ellipsis;` but also need `overflow:hidden` and `white-space:nowrap`. There are so much information about this, e.g. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: @Hoshts: `text-overflow` adds the "..." after each line. That's a cool feature (I'm using it on my site too), but that's not what I'm asking for in this question. I'd like to display "(...)" underneath the last fully displayed sentence.

Comment: I totally misunderstood you. I can see you did put up an example now. Would have made some more sense to me. :D